# Handle "Missing CSRF token" play framework

Tags: playframework, csrf

I want to handle "Missing CSRF Token" error in play framework.

I followed the documentation:

Added following to the application.conf:

```
csrf.error.handler=controllers.ErrorController
```

And added that class in package controllers:

```
package controllers;

import models.Message;
import play.Logger;
import play.data.Form;
import play.mvc.Controller;
import play.mvc.Result;
import views.html.error;

public class ErrorController implements play.filters.csrf.CSRFErrorHandler {
    @Override
    public Result handle(String s) {
        Logger.error("Handl error: " + s);
        return Controller.ok(error.render(Form.form(Message.class), "Fehler aufgetreten!"));
    }
}
```

I'm using playframework 3.9

Every help is appricated
Kind Regards!

Comment: Could you provide the issue you are facing? Are you getting any errors? What exactly is not working?
Your play version number seems off, latest version is 2.4.3.

Comment: oh hahaha; Well i would like to catch the exception... but instead the error page pops up... :) kind regards